# Remapping keyboard

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remapping, numpad

[My italian keyboard - Rog Zepyhrus G14 A401II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4a7i.jpg)My keyboard is missing the numbpad, I'm tryng to change my keys j,k,l to 1,2,3 and so on...
does anyone know how to do it ?

I create a NumLock with

`#b:: NumLock`

and it works in case I do

`1:: Numpad1`

the problem comes when I need to make the '!' (that is ALT+1), as is no longer registred. So 1 becomes 1 everytimes i press, even ALT+1, NumLock on or off. Same things with the letters, if i do

`j:: Numpad1`

j will always returns 1, but I want to have 'j' and 'J' as well.

Thanks,
I'm using AutoHotkeys

Comment: Please explain more what you're trying to do. What do you mean by `!`? What language is your keyboard layout? Do you have keys for `1`, `2` etc?

Comment: Hi, I have a QWERTY keyboard, italian version, without numberpad. 
Some keyboard have the numberpad under the letters in the right side of the keyboard. ex. 
7,8,9 in the keys 7,8,9; 
4,5,6 in the keys U,I,O;
1,2,3 in the keys J,K,L;
0 in M;

The '!' in the italian keyboard is in the key 1.
What I would like to do is create a new key, for ex 'j', that allows me to use j as a regular key j, J as ALT + j, and 1 as NUMLOCK ON + j

Comment: And yes, I do have regualar numbers as 1,2,3... I have a Rog Zephyrus G14 GA401II

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this at the end of your script:

```
#If !GetKeyState("NumLock","T")

    1::1
    j::j
    
    ; ...
    
#If
```

Untested.

Comment: THANKS! It works perfectly! Now I can have a Numpad :) You made my day.